# Why does the meta tag use name-content pairs and not regular attributes?

Tags: html, meta-tags

More of a theoretical question, but wouldn't it make more sense to have only one `meta` tag with a bunch of attribute-value pairs? Instead of:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Joe Schmoe, jks@example.com" />
    <meta name="description" content="An article that summarizes the risks 
        and benefits of playing video games for high school students." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="video games, high school students, 
        development, cognition, learning, problem solving, strategy, 
        parenting, time management, procrastination" />
    <title>I'm About to Graduate but I'm Obsessed with Skyrim</title>
    ...
</head>
```

Wouldn't it save some bytes to just write:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" author="Joe Schmoe, jks@example.com" 
        description="The risks and benefits of playing video games 
            for high school students."
        keywords="video games, high school students, development, 
            cognition, learning, problem solving, strategy, 
            parenting, time management, procrastination" />
    <title>I'm About to Graduate but I'm Obsessed with Skyrim</title>
    ...
</head>
```

If the values of the `name` attribute are preset, why not just make them attributes? My method would be easier and smoother for Webpage authors, and I'm sure it would be easy to re-program Website crawlers/robots to understand it. Relevantly, **is there a reason why it can't be done?**

Comment: @John Conde, if this is considered off topic, please mitigate it to a more appropriate site such as stackoverflow. Thank you.

Comment: This question does not appear to be a good fit for any SE site - please review our [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) and inquire on [meta](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/) if you still feel this question should be migrated.

Answer (score 1):

This is all part of standards implemented through W3C for HTML4.

Specifications for using meta tags here http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4

Write your changes up in a proposal and send it in to the W3C as a suggestion for amending the standards.

Drum up support, get general consensus to get it adopted and get it passed into HTML6.